# Modify given jquery validator method to check if sting contains no URL

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I have a jquery validator method that check if URL is input, it works fine

```
$.validator.addMethod('contains_no_url', function(value, element) {
    var url = $.validator.methods.url.bind(this);
    return url(value, element) || url('http://' + value, element);
}, 'Do not include url');
```

Now I need to modify it to check if a sting contains no URL

I want:

**URL** (True)

**URL** some words (True)

some words **URL** (True)

some words **URL** some words (True)

some words (False)

Note: If modifying the existing method is not recommended for this purpose, please let me know if there exists a regex that can be used to check if sting contains no URL.

**UPDATE for comment by @Wiktor Stribiżew**

New regex will be used with below

```
$.validator.addMethod('contains_no_url', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || SOME_REGEX.test(value);
}, "Do not include url");
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? If we cannot modify the code, where will the regex be used?

Comment: New regex will be used for adding new jquery validate method, please see updated question.

Comment: What do your `rules` say?

Comment: I want to prevent inputting the string that contains url

Comment: As explained in a comment on your other question, your booleans are all backwards.  If you want "no URL", then the method must return `false` when it sees a URL.  For this plugin, `false` => FAIL validation, and `true` => pass validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
$.validator.addMethod('contains_no_url', function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(?!.*(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/\S)(?!.*\bwww\.)/.test(value);
    }, 'Do not include url');

$('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            "url": {
                required: true,
                contains_no_url: true
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form id="myform" action="">
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url" /><br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Here,

- `^` - matches start of string
- `(?!.*https?:\/\/\S)` - fails the match if, after any zero or more chars other than line break chars, there is `http`/`https` or `ftp`/`ftps` followed by an optional `s` and then `://` and then any non-whitespace char
- `(?!.*\bwww\.)` - fails the match if, after any zero or more chars other than line break chars, there is a whole word `www` and then a `.`.

Comment: thank you for your time, please include ftp and www. in regex.